# Reason for approach in step of proof that the outer measure of a set is unchanged by a translation

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

From "An Introduction to Lebesgue Integration and Fourier Series" by Howard J. Wilcox and David L. Myers:

$E$ is the unit interval $[0,1]$.

7.4 Definition: The outer measure $m^{*}(A)$ of any set $A \subset E$ is defined to be the real number $\text{glb} \{m^{*}(G) \mid \text{$A \subset G$ and $G$ open in $E$}\}$.

7.6 Lemma: Let $A \subset E$. Then for any $x$, $m^{*}(A) = m^{*}(x + A)$, where $x + A = \{x + a \mid a \in A\}$ is called the translate of the set $A$ by $x$. (Since we are restricted to subsets of $E$, we may need to translate modulo 1; for example, $[1/2,1] + 1/4 = [3/4,1] \cup [0,1/4]$.)

Proof: If $A$ is an interval or a countable union of pairwise disjoint open intervals, the lemma is clearly true. Thus the lemma holds if $A$ is any open set in $E$. For arbitrary $A \subset E$,

\begin{align*}
m^{*}(x + A) &= \text{glb} \{m^{*}(G) \mid \text{$x + A \subset G$ and $G$ open in $E$}\} \\
&= \text{glb} \{m^{*}(-x + G) \mid \text{$A \subset -x + G$ and $-x + G$ open in $E$}\} \\
&\geq m^{*}(A).
\end{align*}

The proof that $m^{*}(A) \geq m^{*}(x + A)$ is similar.

I am uncertain as to the reason for the approach to the last step. It seems that
$$
\{m^{*}(-x + G) \mid \text{$A \subset -x + G$ and $-x + G$ open in $E$}\} = \{m^{*}(G) \mid \text{$A \subset G$ and $G$ open in $E$}\}
$$

and therefore
\begin{align*}
\text{glb} \{m^{*}(-x + G) \mid \text{$A \subset -x + G$ and $-x + G$ open in $E$}\} &= \text{glb} \{m^{*}(G) \mid \text{$A \subset G$ and $G$ open in $E$}\} \\
&= m^{*}(A).
\end{align*}

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes it is correct. This is same as the first inequality with $A$ replaced by $-x+A$  and then  $x$ changes to $-x$, so you don't even have to write this proof.

Comment: Thank you. Any guesses as to why they didn't do it this way?

Comment: I have no idea why they don't realize this simple fact.

Comment: I'm sorry, I think I misread your first comment. I'm not certain that we can just replace $A$ by $-x + A$ without proof can we?

Comment: I mean, that is what we are attempting to prove.

Comment: If the first inequality holds for an arbitrary set $A $ and arbitrary $x$ we can replace $A$ by $-x+A$.

Comment: I guess maybe I'm not sure what you mean by the first inequality.

Comment: Do you mean $m^{*}(x + A) \geq m^{*}(A)$?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant.

Comment: I see. I was confused because that is not what I was referring to in the question.